# Where a process substitution gets stdin from

Tags: bash

In bash I have

```
grep -vf <(cat myfile <(grep -f myfile otherfile)) otherfile
```

Given the repetition of myfile, I thought I could pipe it via stdin like so

```
cat myfile | grep -vf <(cat - <(grep -f - otherfile))  otherfile
```

However this gives me different results.
So my question is where does the innermost substituted process i.e the grep -f - otherfile, get it's stdin from

A secondary question would be whether there is any advantage to trying to substitute the repeated file name with the same thing passed from stdin

Answer (score 2):

Bash will fork a subshell for process substitution and it will inherit *stdin* from the current shell.

For your case, the whole right side of `|` is also running in a subshell so `<()`'s *stdin* is the same as this subshell. So `<()`'s *stdin* is also from `cat myfile`.

See the following simpler example:

```
[STEP 100] # echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.7(3)-release
[STEP 101] # echo hello | cat <( tr a-z A-Z )
HELLO
[STEP 102] #
```